# Formal definition of big-O when multiple variables are involved?

Tags: asymptotics, definition

I was reading up on various graph algorithms (Dijkstra's algorithm and some variants) and found the runtime $O(m + n \log n)$, where $m$ is the number of edges in the graph and $n$ is the number of nodes.  Intuitively, this makes sense, but I recently realized that I don't know, formally, what this statement means.

The definition of big-O notation that I am familiar with concerns single-variable functions; that is, $f(n) = O(g(n))$ if $\exists n_0, c$ such that $\forall n > n_0. |f(n)| \le c|g(n)|$.  However, this definition doesn't make sense for something like $O(m + n \log n)$, since there are two free parameters here - $m$ and $n$.  Although in the context of graphs there are well-specified relations between $m$ and $n$, in some other algorithms (for example, string matching) the runtime might be described as $O(f(m, n))$ where $m$ and $n$ are completely independent of one another.

My question is this: **what is the formal definition of the statement $f(m, n) = O(g(m, n))$**?  Is it a straightforward generalization of the definition for one variable where we give lower bounds on both $m$ and $n$ that must be simultaneously satisfied, or is there some other definition defined in terms of limits?

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty well explained in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables) and papers like  [On Asymptotic Notation with Multiple Variables](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14776509847592366772&hl=en&as_sdt=0,36&sciodt=0,36)

Comment: @MarkBeadles- Wow, I feel silly... I completely missed that section.  Thanks for spotting that!  If you promote that link to an answer, I can accept it to mark the question closed.

Comment: Will do, glad to help.

Comment: this question at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/asymptotic-analysis-for-two-variables
might also help.

Comment: Depending on which input you are considering, the other can be held constant. The fact the other inputs are temporarily considered constant doesn't  harm the definition, even though that constant could also be removed for that considertion. What do you think of this approach?

Answer (score 15):

Bachman-Landau big O and similar notation for multiple variables is pretty well explained in [the wikipedia article on big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables), as well as papers like Rodney R. Howell's [On Asymptotic Notation with Multiple Variables](http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~rhowell/asymptotic.pdf).

Comment: I don't think this [fundamentally answers the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) as it is "barely more than a link to an external site".