# Can we define limiting behavior function of higher order in terms of norms?

Tags: asymptotics

Let $f(x):=x$ and $g(x):=x^{2}$, then we say that $f=\mathcal{O}(g)$ if there exists $\alpha,x_{0}>0$ such that:
$$
|f(x)|\leqslant\alpha|g(x)|
$$
for all $x>x_{0}$

My question is if now $f,g\colon \mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$, defined by $f(\mathbf{x}):=\mathbf{x}$ and $g(\mathbf{x}):=\mathbf{x}^{2}$ (element-wise squaring) then can we say that:

> $f=\mathcal{O}(g)$ if there exists $\alpha>0$ and $\mathbf{x}_{0}$ such that: $$\|f\|_{p}\leqslant \alpha\|g\|_{p}$$
> for all $\|\mathbf{x}\|_{p}>\|\mathbf{x}_{0}\|_{p}$?

Comment: You can say $f=\mathcal{O}(\|g\|_p)$.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are defining a new non-standard variant of the $\,f=\mathcal{O}(g)\,$ notation which is now defined for multivariable functions. What do you want to know about it?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/96809/620957. See in particluar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables and https://people.cis.ksu.edu/~rhowell/asymptotic.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You extend big O notation for multivariable functions. It doesn't conflict with the existing notation. However it is non-standart, so you should give the definition every time you use it (once per article or homework).